# Unable to cast IAsyncResult.AsyncState

Tags: c#, sockets, asynchronous

I am trying to cast IAsyncResult.AsyncState to class StateObject. But it is giving a cast error since AsyncState is of type Socket. I need to get the byte data from the result. I have just started a Server project and i am not familiar with that.

```
public class StateObject
    {
        // Client socket.
        public Socket workSocket = null;
        // Size of receive buffer.
        public const int BufferSize = 256;
        // Receive buffer.
        public byte[] buffer = new byte[BufferSize];
        // Received data string.
        public StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    }
```

This is the OnReceiveHandlerClass

```
private void Receive(IAsyncResult result)
    {

      StateObject ss = (StateObject)result.AsyncState;
      ......
      }
```

Thanks in advance..

Comment: friends the issue is fixed...:-)

Comment: Post the fix as an answer and accept it, so future generations of programmers might be spared the same fate.  :)

Comment: actually it was my mistake as i didn't know even the basics.anyway i will post the mistake.as you said it might help someone....:-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was getting the error because i was sending a different object in the BeginReceive method in case of sending StateObject

```
Correct method:
Socket.BeginReceive(StateObject.DataBuffer, 0, (int)StateObject.DataLength, 
                      SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(this.Receive),StateObject);
```

The last parameter was supposed to be of type StateObject and i send an object as i was not known what to send for that parameter.